# How do you combine the data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
create table table1 (
    header bit,
    [type] char(1),
    Intype varchar(3),
    agrid int,
    affid int,
    inno varchar(10),
    amount int
);

create table table2 (
    header bit,
    [type] char(1),
    Intype varchar(3),
    agrid int,
    affid int,
    inno varchar(10),
    amount int
);
```

### Scenario 1:

```
insert into table1 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(0, 'D','001',18,84,'001',null),
(0, 'N', '001', 18,84,'001',null);

insert into table2 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(1, null, null,18,84, '001', 90),
(1, null, null,18,84, '001', 60),
(1, null, null,18,84, '001', 84);
```

For every header trailer 0 record, i need to show the related trailer 1 record joining on inno , affid, agrid. Please let m eknow how can i achieve this

I need:

```
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount
0      , 'D' , '001' , 18 , 84 , '001' , null     ----table 1 record for type D
1      , null, null, 18, 84, 001, 90          
1, null, null,18,84, 001, 60
1, null, null,18,84, 001, 84
0, 'N', '001', 18,84,'001',null             ----table 1 record for type N
1      , null, null, 18, 84, 001, 90          
1, null, null,18,84, 001, 60
1, null, null,18,84, 001, 84
0, 'N', '001', 18,84,'001',null
```

### Scenario 2:

```
insert into table1 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(0, 'D','001',14,95,'001',null),
(0, 'D', '001', 14,95,'008',null),
(0, 'N', '001', 14,95,'008',null);

insert into table2 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(1, null, null,14,95, '001', 11),
(1, null, null,14,95, '008', 23);
```

I need:

```
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount
0, 'D','001',14,95,'001',null    ----table 1 record for type D
1, null, null,14,95, 001, 11         
0, 'D', '001', 14,95,'008',null  ---table 1 record for type D
1, null, null,14,95, 008, 23
0, 'N', '001', 14,95,'008',null             ----table 1 record for type N
1, null, null,14,95, 008, 23
```

I tried with some joins, it didn't work.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statements are missing `NULL/NOT NULL` declarations, without them the default is `NULL` (which is a bad default, imo) which is not good for database design - you're also missing `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, which you **need** in order to have a maintainable database.

Comment: I really don't see why `NULL`able columns are "bad", @Dai ; that's quite a bold and controversial statement in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu They aren't. I'm saying that _in the absence_ of `NULL/NOT NULL` modifiers in column definitions the ISO SQL standard should have been written to assume `NOT NULL` instead of `NULL` - but it's a historical decision that we're now stuck with that we have to suffer the consequences for.

Comment: But you go on to say that `NULL` is *not good* for database design, @Dai. If it's "not good" then it's *bad*, no? You state *"without them the default is `NULL` which is not good for database design"*

Comment: @Larnu I misspoke. What I meant was that (as in the OP's tables) when _every column_ is implicitly `NULL` by default _when they shouldn't be_, is going to cause issues in future because the DB is no-longer self-documenting, so tooling and other people have no idea if `NULL` _should_ be allowed in the column or not.

Comment: That I don't disagree with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort then, by adding more columns

the main part is that both get a row_number that can join table1 and table1, the constant sorter is necessary as header is  binary and can only handle two different tables, if you have more, it will be useful

To get the right order for amount, you need an aditional sorting column, like an indetidy

Tables are by nature unsorted, so the result can differ

```
SELECT 
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agrid , affid, inno ORDER BY agrid) rn,1 sorter
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
t2.header , t2.[type] , t2.Intype  ,t2.agrid , t2.affid, t2.inno,t2.amount,
t1.rn,2
FROM table2 t2 JOIN (SELECT 
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agrid , affid, inno ORDER BY agrid) rn
FROM table1)
   t1 ON t1.agrid = t2.agrid 
  AND t1.affid = t2.affid AND t1.inno = t2.inno
ORDER BY agrid , affid, inno,rn,sorter
```

| header | type | Intype | agrid | affid | inno | amount | rn | sorter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | D | 001 | 18 | 84 | 001 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 90 | 1 | 2 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 60 | 1 | 2 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 84 | 1 | 2 |
| False | N | 001 | 18 | 84 | 001 | *null* | 2 | 1 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 90 | 2 | 2 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 84 | 2 | 2 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 18 | 84 | 001 | 60 | 2 | 2 |

```
truncate table  table1
```

```
truncate table table2
```

```
insert into table1 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(0, 'D','001',14,95,'001',null),
(0, 'D', '001', 14,95,'008',null),
(0, 'N', '001', 14,95,'008',null);

insert into table2 (header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount)
values
(1, null, null,14,95, '001', 11),
(1, null, null,14,95, '008', 23);
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
SELECT 
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agrid , affid, inno ORDER BY agrid) rn,1 sorter
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
t2.header , t2.[type] , t2.Intype  ,t2.agrid , t2.affid, t2.inno,t2.amount,
t1.rn,2
FROM table2 t2 JOIN (SELECT 
header , [type] , Intype  ,agrid , affid, inno,amount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agrid , affid, inno ORDER BY agrid) rn
FROM table1)
   t1 ON t1.agrid = t2.agrid 
  AND t1.affid = t2.affid AND t1.inno = t2.inno
ORDER BY agrid , affid, inno,rn,sorter
```

| header | type | Intype | agrid | affid | inno | amount | rn | sorter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | D | 001 | 14 | 95 | 001 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 14 | 95 | 001 | 11 | 1 | 2 |
| False | D | 001 | 14 | 95 | 008 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 14 | 95 | 008 | 23 | 1 | 2 |
| False | N | 001 | 14 | 95 | 008 | *null* | 2 | 1 |
| True | *null* | *null* | 14 | 95 | 008 | 23 | 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mNedQLsu)